# Lubuntu 14.04 HDMI no sound on TV

Tags: sound, 14.04, lubuntu, software-installation, hdmi

I plugged in the HDMI-emphasized text cable from  my TV and plugged it in my desktop and when I restarted the computer it has a clear picture but no sound at all.

I have looked for a solution but can't find one.

I have downloaded and installed these and still don't have sound:

```
alsa-hda-dkms_0.201204101019~maverick1_all.deb
alsa-hda-dkms_0.201210261053~natty1_all.deb
oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201405091731~ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to system settings. Select sound (under the section hardware). Then change the output to HDMI.

[image: Sound Settings]